# python loop create i know its simple but I do not know what's wrong

Tags: python

New to python trying to create while loop that print out 1 through 10 not just 10:

```
I=0
while I != 10:
    I +=1
print (I)
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Talk through it calmly. How many times did the `print` happen? How many times *should* it happen? How many times do you expect code that is *inside* the loop to run? How many times do you expect code that is *outside* the loop to run? Therefore, should the `print` be inside the loop, or outside the loop? How do you tell whether something is inside or outside the loop? Therefore, *is* the `print` outside the loop? Do you see how to solve the problem now?

Comment: @Aria West, if there's an answer that worked for you you should accept it so that others can understand it's a working answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have to put `print()` in the `while` loop:

```py
I=0
while I != 11: # if I != 10 then 10 won't be printed
    I +=1
    print(I)
```

You can also use `for` loop:

```
for i in range(11):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `print` statement into the `while` loop.

```
I = 0
while I < 10:
    I +=1
    print(I)
```

This will print:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Your code is actually right just you have to indent print() inside while loop

> `.....print(I)`

```
I=0
while I != 10:
    I +=1
    print (I)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know that in Python `indentation` is compulsory, for example:

```
// JavaScript
function foo(arg) {console.log(arg);}
// Is equivalent to:
function foo(arg) {
console.log(arg);
}
// and to:
function foo(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
}
```

In Python it's different:

```
# Python
for i in range(10):
    print(i) # This will print 10 times
print(i) # This will print 1 time (and in SHELL it will raise a SyntaxError)
```

---

In your case you just have to correct indentation...

```
I = 0 # Remember in Python the spaces in assignations
while I != 10:
    I +=1
    print (I) # At the same level as the previous line
```

...otherwise it will be interpreted as outside the `while` loop.

---

A better way to do this is using a `for` loop iterating over a `range` object:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```